# MathJax not rendering Tex in display style

Tags: pandoc, html, mathjax

I'm rendering a LaTeX file to HTML via Pandoc, and the output has one key difference that I can't figure out how to fix. In my LaTeX'd PDFs, I have some math in display mode that renders as:

[image]

But in the Pandoc'd/MathJax'd HTML, the sigma renders in inline style (smaller, and with the sub/superscripts to the right):

[image]

The code generating this equation is:

```
$$\displaystyle \frac{ \overbrace{x^{n}}^{\text{the $k=0$ term}} + \overbrace{ {\color{blue} {n\choose {n-1}}x^{n-1}h^{1}} }^{\text{the $k=1$ term}} \,\,+ \overbrace{ {\color{red} \sum_{k=2}^{k=n}{n\choose {n-k}}x^{n-k}h^{k} } }^{\text{the terms from $k=2$ to $k=n$}} \quad-\quad x^n}{h}$$
```

This happens even when I try to actively force it into display style by including \displaystyle (as I have above). Any ideas? How can I force MathJax to render the iterated sum sigma in display style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Mathjax is not LaTeX and pure Mathjax questions are off topic here, sorry.

Comment: note mathjax rendering is off topic (it uses javascript not tex) in latex, `\displaystyle` does nothing after `$$`  as that is displaystyle alreadynormally numerator of a fraction would be set in textstyle it's an side effect of `\overbrace` that it is set in displaystyle. You could try `\overbrace{\displaystyle\sum...`

Answer (score 3):

The `\displaystyle` you have does nothing at all.

You need to issue it in the first argument to `\frac`, which by default is typeset in `\textstyle`.

What's the reason for “different” rendering? Because in TeX `\overbrace` forces `\displaystyle`, but MathJax doesn't. Anyway, it's better to make your intentions clear and not to rely on implementation details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\displaystyle
  {\overbrace{x^{n}}^{\text{the $k=0$ term}}} + 
  {\overbrace{\color{blue} \binom{n}{n-1}x^{n-1}h^{1}}^{\text{the $k=1$ term}}} +
  {\overbrace{\color{red} \sum_{k=2}^{k=n}\binom{n}{n-k}x^{n-k}h^{k}}^
    {\text{the terms from $k=2$ to $k=n$}}- x^n}}
  {h}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For MathJax

```
$$\require{color}
\frac{\displaystyle
  {\overbrace{x^{n}}^{\text{the $k=0$ term}}} + 
  {\overbrace{\color{blue} \binom{n}{n-1}x^{n-1}h^{1}}^{\text{the $k=1$ term}}} +
  {\overbrace{\color{red} \sum_{k=2}^{k=n}\binom{n}{n-k}x^{n-k}h^{k}}^
    {\text{the terms from $k=2$ to $k=n$}}- x^n}}
  {h}
$$
```

[image]

Note the additional braces around `\overbrace{...}^{...}` to get the right spacing. Also `\binom` should be preferred over `\choose`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add `\limits` after each `\sum`---that seems to force MathJax to render the sums the way I want it. Still, I don't have a good underlying theory of why/how MathJax is rendering things differently than TeX.

Comment: mathjax shares no code with latex so the extent that it appears to make similar rendering in some cases is a credit to its (very impressive) implementation. The fact that it does not follow all quirks like `\overbrace` forcing display style is not that surprising.